# React navigation - handling going back after deleting object from redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm creating an app that uses redux to store all objects added by the user. I have a home screen where all objects are displayed, and from which the user can navigate to the specific one. On that screen, he can edit it and delete it from the app.
I have a problem with implementing delete functionality, I want to dispatch action and navigate to the home screen. Currently, my code looks like that:

```
        // that's how I get object from store in Plant component
        const plant = useSelector((state) =>
        state.plants.plants.find((plant) => plant.id === props.route.params.plantId));

        // onPress deleteButton
        props.navigation.goBack();
        dispatch(deletePlant(plant.id));

        // reducer
        const updatedPlants = [...state.plants].filter((plant) => plant.id !== action.plantId);
        return { ...state, plants: updatedPlants };
```

But the problem is, my app crashes after deleting the plant because the plant variable is undefined on the Plant screen. Currently, I found a workaround, in the render function, I check if the plant variable is undefined, and if it is I just return empty View.

I feel there's a better way to do it, could you help me with it?

Comment: // try reversing order

 dispatch(deletePlant(plant.id));
 props.navigation.goBack();

Comment: I tried this one, but still, I keep getting an error from plant component

Answer (score 0):

It have to nothing to do with `going back`, it's about render. No error should be throw during render.

1. if you are looping `plants` in your home page and rendering them, there should be no problem. unless your `deletePlant` is setting that data to `undefined`, not remove it from array like using `splice`.
2. if your home screen are hardcoded to display items inside plants, then check for a `undefined` value is common. if `empty view` is what you concern about, you can also return `null` as well.

Comment: The problem isn't with home screen, but with plant screen (that on with details of plant), I think react tries to re-render it before goBack() is called, and gets undefinded, because find method didn't found anything. Is there any way to delay this re-render?

Comment: Yes, with shouldComponentUpdate. return false if you want to skip that render.